# Probability with Bernoulli Trials

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

A fair die is rolled repeatedly and each roll counts as a success if a 6 appears. What is the Probability that exactly three 6's will appear in the first 12 rolls? I believe this problem invilves the Bernoulli Process, but I'm not sure how to find the values amd plug them in correctly. Please advise.

Comment: Binomial distribution.

Answer (score 3):

rolls :=$n=12$
hits :=$k=3$
probability for hit :=$p_0=\frac{1}{6}$

Use general formula for Bernoulli Trials

$$P(n,k,p_0)=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p_0^k(1-p_0)^{n-k}$$

$$P=\frac{12!}{3!9!}(\frac{1}{6})^3(1-\frac{1}{6})^{12-3}$$

Comment: To clarify this answer (in words): the first term is "how can we choose where these three 6s appear in these twelve rolls"; the second term is "what is the probability that we get a 6 in each of these three rolls"; and the third term is "what is the probability that all of the other nine rolls are **not** a 6."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to explain the calculation with \underbrace but it didn't work.